# SQL Server: Selecting rows with the latest date for each part

Tags: sql-server, date, distinct

Im just learning SQL hence I struggle a bit to produce the output I'd want to.

Suppose I have a table X shown below:

```
-------Date ------- Part ------- Value

01-01-2005           A           200

01-01-2006           A           100

01-01-2007           A           300

02-02-2010           B           450

02-02-2011           B           320
```

and from X I'd like to get these:

```
-------Date ------- Part ------- Value

01-01-2007           A           300

02-02-2011           B           320
```

Basically what I want to do is to get for each distinct part only one record - the one that has the latest date. Value column needs to remain in the result!

How do I do that (assuming it's possible)? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max within a timeframe with date duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041730/max-within-a-timeframe-with-date-duplicates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH LatestRecords
AS
  (
   SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PART ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
   FROM TABLEX
  )
SELECT * FROM LatestRecords
WHERE rn = 1
```